# Using GeoDjango model as an abstract class

Tags: django-models, geodjango

I'm playing with GeoDjango and have some doubts. I'll really appreciate any comment and suggestion.

This is my problem. First, I've defined this (abstract) class:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.geos import *

class LocatableModel(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=48, blank=True)
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    locality = models.CharField(max_length=48, blank=True)
    sub_locality = models.CharField(max_length=48, blank=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=48, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    point = models.PointField(null=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Second, I've defined this other 'Entity' class, which
represents a person or organization related to my site:

```
from django.db import models

class Entity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    website = models.URLField(verify_exists=False, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    ...
```

Finally, I've created a class from the previous ones:

```
import LocatableModel
import Entity

class Organization(Entity, LocatableModel):
    timetable = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ...
```

In my views, I'd like to find organizations near a specific point:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D

def index(request):
    pnt = Point(12.4604, 43.9420)
    dic = { 'orgs': Organization.objects.filter(point__distance__lte=(pnt, D(km=7))) }
    return render_to_response('index.html', dic)
```

But I receive the error:

"Join on field 'point' not permitted. Did you misspell 'distance' for
the lookup type?"

I think I'm doing a mess with the model 'objects' property, but I'm not sure. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error has been seen before, and claimed to be solved in this ticket 3 years ago:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9364

When I ran into this same problem, I noticed in the ticket that the query manager was set explicitly to GeoManager in the inherited model(s).  So adding a line like,

```
class Organization(Entity, LocatableModel): 
    timetable = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ...
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

...may solve the issue you're seeing, it worked for me.